# PHP date() reliability

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I am building a package that heavily relies on the current week number of the year as well as the forthcoming 4 or 5 week numbers. I know that sounds kind of confusing but lets say this week amounts to the 51st one of the year. The next 4 week numbers would be:

1. 52
2. 1
3. 2
4. 3

My Question:

How reliable is PHP's `date()` function? The library isn't very well documented and the comments underneath make me a little nervous about using it. I am using the following to get the current week number:

```
echo $weekNumber = date("W");
```

Is that a reliable way of working with dates? Any recommendations? I am not very good with dates and times and the sheer size of the various functions available in PHP's native library has left me very confused (`time()`, `strtotime()`, `date()` etc).

Comment: It's going to be more reliable than anything custom you come up with. (Most of) Those functions have been thoroughly tested before they're released

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about it not being "reliable"... do you not trust it?

Comment: `date()` just formats whatever UNIX timestamp you pass to it (or uses current time if none given); what unreliability do you see? The example you are giving is working exactly as it should - e.g. 2012-01-01 is in week 52 of 2011, that is a feature of ISO 8601.

Comment: Yeah, I am a little worried about 'consistency'. I don't want it getting confused by leap year or some other natures way of confusing our puny minds. (i blame y2k for instilling this paranoia, i was a kid back then and i can distinctly recall the very nervous look on the faces of various IT pros... all in vain though.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just done a quick test with the following code:

```
echo date('W', strtotime('2011/12/31')) . '<br>';
echo date('W', strtotime('2011/12/31 +1 week')) . '<br>';
echo date('W', strtotime('2011/12/31 +2 week')) . '<br>';
echo date('W', strtotime('2011/12/31 +3 week')) . '<br>';
```

Here we start with the 31st Dec 2011 (last day this year), then we print 3 more `W` weeks, which gives this output:

```
52
01
02
03
04
```

Which does exactly what you want. If PHP's `date()` function didn't work properly, it would have either been removed (bad!), or rewritten until it did work.

Comment: Thank you. I will go with this. I am still worried. Probably because this is unknown territory for me. But thanks :)

Edit: That is a good argument you make for date(). *Nerves -1*

Comment: You shouldn't worry. `date()` has been used and tested for literally _years_, so any bugs at all with all sorts of input data (fringe cases, etc) will have been fixed long ago.

Answer (score 0):

I would worry more about the reliability of the system clock.